# "thought I'd/wanted to"

Tags: idiomatic-language, colloquial-language, conversation

A man walks up to a woman at the bar in a bar and they fall into conversation. He squeezes into the conversation that he's a lawyer. The conversation goes on. At some point in the conversation he tells her that he actually saw her in the bar yesterday too and overheard her talking with a friend about the divorce she's going through at the moment and that her ex husband is trying to rip her off. He continues...

> 1) That's why I just thought I'd let you know that I work as a lawyer.
>
> 2) That's why I just wanted to let you know that I work as a lawyer.

Are both of these sentences correct and natural in this context if he's referring to earlier in the conversation where he mentioned that he was a lawyer? I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: They're ok, but I would omit the "just" from them. It feels awkward to me.

Comment: Aside: "at the bar in a bar" is a bit awkward. Perhaps "in a bar."